# How can I automatically set “sheets last updated” in a cell on Google Docs Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Simple task!.. output a date and time every time something in the sheet is edited!

```
function onEdit() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets("Data");
   var cell = ss.sheet.getRange("F2");
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");
   ss.sheet.cell.setValue(date);
 };
```

And just for knowledge how to do it only if the edits where in a sheet called FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

try `if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName() == "FAQ")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var feuilleActive = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var rangActif = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var utilisateur = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var index = rangActif.getRowIndex();
  var derniereLigne = feuilleActive.getLastRow();
  var derniereCol = feuilleActive.getLastColumn();

  var derniereCelluleUtilisee = feuilleActive.getRange(index,derniereCol);
  var derniereCelluleFeuille = feuilleActive.getRange(index +1,derniereCol);
  Logger.log(derniereCelluleFeuille);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");


  // indique un commentaire dans la cellule modifiée
  derniereCelluleUtilisee.setComment("Dernière modification : " + rangActif.getA1Notation() +' réalisée par '+ utilisateur);
  // envoie un message
  ss.toast('Dernière modification = '+ rangActif.getA1Notation()+' réalisé par '+ utilisateur);
  // indique la date de dernière modification dans la dernière ligne de la première colonne
  derniereCelluleFeuille.setValue("Dernière mise à jour le " + date);
  derniereCelluleFeuille.setFontStyle("italic");
}
```